# Get table range in VBA (dynamic)

Tags: excel, vba, filter, range

I have a program in VBA that I am working on that filters values from a table. I'm trying to make this a generic program that works with all tables that you give it. In my program I have to set the range of the table that it is filtering: Set rng = dataSheet.Range("A1:F78"). I was wondering if there was a way to get the Range of a table in excel that has some sort of text value in it so I don't have to specify it in every macro. I guess this is a type of dynamic range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is one cell of your range which is always within your table, like `A1` would be always top-left corner of the table. And if there is continuous range of cells until the end of your table you could use `.CurrentRegion property` in this way:

```
Set rng = dataSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```